# GridView scrolls very slowly

Tags: java, android, android-gridview, layout-inflater

This is my custom adapter class for my GridView. I had tried to optimize speed of grid scrolling by making call to layout inflater once and also use view holder but now it's very slow to scroll.

```
private Context mContext;
private final String[] web;
private final int[] Imageid;

public CustomGrid(Context c, String[] web, int[] Imageid) {
    mContext = c;
    this.Imageid = Imageid;
    this.web = web;
}

class MyViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;

    MyViewHolder(View v) {
        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
    }

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View grid = convertView;
    MyViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (grid == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
        viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(grid);
        grid.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        grid = convertView;
        viewHolder= (MyViewHolder) grid.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.textView.setText(web[position]);
    viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
    return grid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should work fine. The only possible cause is that the images that you are loading are so large that the memory cannot load all of them at the same time.

You may want to try with smaller size. Or you can consider using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load your images, as it resizes the images according to the ImageView's size.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [recycleView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) for better performance and smooth scrolling.
2. Use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for image loading.